# How to typesafely transform sumtypes in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

Given the following sumtype:

```kotlin
sealed interface Node
data class Values(...) : Node
data class Container<V : Node>(val nodes: Map<String, V>) : Node
```

it's possible to construct types like `Container<Container<Values>>`.

Given another sumtype with a similar structure

```kotlin
sealed interface Diff
data class ValuesDiff(...) : Diff
data class ContainerDiff<V : Diff>(val nodes: Map<String, V>) : Diff
```

types with a similar structure can be created e.g. `ContainerDiff<ContainerDiff<ValuesDiff>>`.

I am looking for a method to transform the 1st sumtype into the 2nd, while keeping the structure.
Something like this:

```kotlin
val node: Container<Container<Values>>
val diff: ContainerDiff<ContainerDiff<ValuesDiff>> = myFunction(node)
```

In Scala 3 there are [Match Types](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/match-types.html#).

Is there a way to do that in kotlin?

The best approach I found so far is to use a generic parameter.

```kotlin
sealed interface Diff<T : Node>
data class ValuesDiff(...) : Diff<Values>
data class ContainerDiff<V : Node>(val nodes: Map<String, Diff<V>>) : Diff<Container<V>>
```

Based on the interface and the generic parameter i provide extension methods to do the casting.

```kotlin
val myDiff: ContainerDiff<Container<Values>>
val theFirstContainer: Diff<Container<Values>> = myDiff.nodes.values.first() // here I would like to have the type ContainerDiff<ValuesDiff> 
// so to cast this I use 2 extension methods
fun Diff<Values>.cast() = this as ValuesDiff
fun <V : Node> Diff<Container<V>>.cast() = this as ContainerDiff<V>
// using the cast() extension method
val castedContainer: ContainerDiff<Values> = theFirstContainer.cast()
// and again for the nested Node
val castedValue: ValuesDiff = castedContainer.nodes.values.first().cast()
```

Is there a way to get the desired type directly without using the cast() extension methods?
Have you had this problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: Casting `Diff` to `ContainterDiff` is a downcast, so it may fail with `ClassCastException`. IMHO explicit cast is unavoidable, due to reasons outside generics. We both know that there are no other options thanks to sealed, but type erasure can't know that.